# Why will signal TSTP received by sigchld_handler instead of sigtstp_handler?

Tags: c, signals

This is my own shell program.

The TSTP signal is sent by this part of main function, this c file will be ran as a program in the shell.

When the c program runs, it's in a forked child process, when it sends TSTP to itself, the expectation is that the signal should be received by tstp-handler (the printf should be showing up) and then the child process stopped.

However, it's the child-handler that received a signal(17), i.e the printf in sigchld_handler was called without printf in sigtstp_handler being called first. It's the parent process that gets received the sigchld signal, how can I make the child process itself receive the TSTP signal?

All handlers registered correctly as CTRL+Z will invoke the tstp-handler correctly.

Can anyone please help me with this part? Very much appreciate it.

If you need all the source code, please find it [here](https://github.com/haoboliu66/CSAPP-15-213/blob/master/05-shell-lab/tsh.c)

```
// the program sending the signal
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i, secs;
    pid_t pid;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <n>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }
    secs = atoi(argv[1]);

    for (i=0; i < secs; i++)
       sleep(1);

    pid = getpid();
    // printf("main process id: %d\n", pid);
    if (kill(-pid, SIGTSTP) < 0)
       fprintf(stderr, "kill (tstp) error");

    exit(0);

}
```

```
void eval(char *cmdline){
    char *argv[MAXARGS];
    char buf[MAXLINE];
    strcpy(buf, cmdline);
    int bg = parseline(buf, argv);
    if(argv[0] == NULL) return;
    
    if(builtin_cmd(argv)){
        return;
    }

    /* not built-in commands */
    pid_t cpid;
    
    sigset_t mask, prev_mask;
    sigemptyset(&mask);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGCHLD);

    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, &prev_mask);


    cpid = fork();
    if(cpid == 0){ // child

        setpgid(0, 0);

        sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &mask, NULL);

        Execve(argv[0], argv, environ);

    }else{

        addjob(jobs, cpid, (bg? BG: FG), cmdline);
  
        sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &prev_mask, NULL);


        if(bg){
             printf("[%d] (%d) %s", pid2jid(cpid), cpid, cmdline);
             /* when bg job is done, how is the child process reaped? => sigchld_handler will be triggered */
        }else{
            /*  fg job, parent process blocked;
                delete fg job after it's complete(in sigchld_handler)
            */
            waitfg(cpid);
        }
    }
}
```

```
void sigtstp_handler(int sig){
    //printf("=== in sigtstp_handler, sig: %d, from %d\n", sig, getpid());
    pid_t foreground_pid = fgpid(jobs);

    if(foreground_pid == 0) return;

    struct job_t *fg_job = getjobpid(jobs, foreground_pid);
    if(fg_job != NULL && fg_job->state == FG){
        pid_t pgid = getpgid(fg_job->pid);
        printf("Job [%d] (%d) stopped by signal %d\n", fg_job->jid, fg_job->pid, sig);
        Kill(-pgid, SIGTSTP);
    }
}
```

```
void sigchld_handler(int sig){
    // printf("=== in sigchld_handler: %d\n", sig);
    pid_t cpid;
    int status; 

    if((cpid = waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG | WUNTRACED)) > 0){


        if(WIFEXITED(status)){
            // printf("in sigchld_handler, terminated cpid: %d\n", cpid);
            deletejob(jobs, cpid);
        }
        if(WIFSTOPPED(status)){
            struct job_t *stopped_job = getjobpid(jobs, cpid);
            stopped_job->state = ST;
        }
        if(WIFSIGNALED(status)){
            deletejob(jobs, cpid);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code that sets up the TSTP signal hander?

Comment: in the main function of the shell program

Comment: `execve()` will reset the signal handling to the defaults. Obviously, the process cannot use any existing signal handler functions in its code because `execve()` is replacing the process's code.

Comment: I see, is there any ways to get around this?

Comment: The executed program can set up its own signal handler to catch the signal.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm trying to figure out how to do this in the shell code only